# Django change request.path in middleware (to authenticate by token in url)

Tags: django, middleware, django-middleware

Dear omnoscient beings at Stackoverflow,

In Django 1.3 I am making a process_request middleware that gets a token from an url, logs the user in (if it's correct) and removes the token from the url. However:

I) Django recommends against accessing POST/GET data in middleware, I'm not really sure why so... Does the same apply to request.path ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view

II) I want to remove the token from the URL, so `/album3/pic42/~53Cr3t70K3n/like/` -> `/album3/pic42/like/`. Changing request.path however does not work. The page will not be found, while

- The middleware does process correctly (verified by print)
- Directly entering `/album3/pic42/like/` does work
- The error (with token) shows `Request URL: http://www.site.com/album3/pic42/like/`

Is there a fix for this, or am I approaching this from the wrong angle entirely?

Thanks in advance!

**I just realized that to change it client side, obviously I need a redirect (why didn't I think of that...). However, it would still be useful to be able to rewrite it just server-side without a new request, for example for accessing a personalized image.**

---

P.s.: more details if needed, *feel free to skip*

I am working on a site that (will) sends personalized emails to users. I would like users to be able to click links in the email and be logged in automatically, by means of a token in the email link. This is in addition to normal login. (I know it's a less secure because people might forward an e-mail, but it's good enough for my site). The url would look something like this:
/album3/pic42/~53Cr3t70K3n/like/ (with http://www.site.com stripped, Django does that)

I am writing a middleware to match this and log the user in when appropriate, a authentication backend for accepting a token as valid credentials and a token model.

---

Middleware process_request function:
    def process_request(self, request):

```
    if '/~' in request.path:
        result = re.search('(.*)/~(.+?)/(.*)', request.path)
        (uidb36, token) = result.group(2).split('-', 2)
        user = authenticate(uidb36 = uidb36, token = token)
        if user: login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('%s/%s' % (result.group(1), result.group(3)) + ('?' + '&'.join('='.join(item) for item in request.GET.items()) if request.GET else ''))
    return None
```

Right now it works with redirects, I'd like to also be able to do it internally.

Comment: Please, provide relevant parts of your middleware code.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you'd like to do it internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mess up with [upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers), I have a better solution for you:

1. **Create a rule in your urls.py to specifically catch visits with tokens**

   Put it at the start of the `urlpatterns` to make sure that it will be evaluated first. Something like this will do:

   ```
   (r'/~', 'my_app_name.my_redirect_view'),
   ```
2. **Create a view**:

   ```
   def my_redirect_view(request):
       #Compiled regular expressions work much faster
       beloved_tokens = re.compile(r'(.*)/~(.+?)/(.*)')
       result = beloved_tokens.search(request.path)
       try:
           (uidb36, token) = result.group(2).split('-', 2)
           path_end = result.group(3)
       # We use "try" to be sure that no one had
       # messed with our beloved tokens:
       except AttributeError: 
           raise Http404
       else:
           user = authenticate(uidb36 = uidb36, token = token)
           if user: 
               login(request, user)
               return HttpResponseRedirect('%s/%s' % (result.group(1), result.group(3)) + ('?' + '&'.join('='.join(item) for item in request.GET.items()) if request.GET else ''))
           else:
               raise Http404
   ```

Comment: Of course, you can add some additional processing in order to strip token from request.GET. But the whole concept remains the same: **we don't need middleware** to solve the issue.

Comment: Using url match is a good idea, I hadn't thought of that! (Also adding try except is a good idea).But is there a way to go on to match the url stripped of token after this, because it'd also like a method that doesn't need redirect...

Comment: @Mark, why don't you add a token at the end of the url? Is there a specific reason to put it in the middle?

Comment: You mean to match them with the normal views instead, and read the token either at the start of the view or with middleware? r'^album/' instead of r'^album/$', I guess that'd work if I put things like r'^album2' before r'^album' (or it'd match the first one)...

Comment: In any case, if you use middleware or normal views, having the token at the end of an url is much better. You should probably use token as a GET parameter like `?token=...` and do as @Anurag suggested.

Answer (score 1):

IMO changing request.path is more bad(if it can be called bad) compared to accessing GET/POST parameters, so just pass token as GET parameter and login based on token and do not redirect or do request.path modifications

I see token as a added attribute to a valid url, hence a middleware acknowledges that and does something with that token, but url still is handled by the correct view, so middleware to me seems a very logical fit here.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use middleware at all.

Comment: Yes I can see how GET would be more appropriate for this than request.path, but it apparently gives trouble with upload handlers (which I don't know yet if I will need later). But I guess I can use GET at least for the redirect-way, in which case that problem doesn't exist!

Comment: @Ivan Kharlamov, but middleware makes thing easier to handle and can avoid a redirect

Comment: @Mark, if you are modifying upload handlers, you can do them before token middleware and everything will be fine, csrf middleware also accesses POST params

Comment: @AnuragUniyal, you are probably right, it is better to use middleware. And it is [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/?from=olddocs#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry).